# Create table with missing and present dates from fact and dim tables SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Given fact table with some dates and dim table that has all dates , need to create a table like below with Missing and present dates:

Fact Table

```
Fact_date                                
2018-01-04                               
2018-01-05                             
2018-01-22
```

dim_date

```
 date_dt
 2018-01-01
 2018-01-02
 2018-01-03 …
```

From above two tables, create this below table

```
Type                 start_date     end_date
Missing             2018-01-01   2018-01-03
Present             2018-01-04   2018-01-05
Missing             2018-01-06   2018-01-22
```

Here's what I have till now:

```
with a as (
(select date_dt as date_col,
       'missing' as type
       from dimdate)
union all 
 (select fact_date as date_col,
         'present' as type
         from fact_table)
    ),
   b as (    
select date_col,
       type,
       row_number() over (order by date_col asc) as seq
   from a
         )
         

select type, 
min(date_col) as start_date, max(date_col) as end_date
from b
group by dateadd(d, -seq, date_col),type
```

This is giving me like this:

```
Type                 start_date     end_date
Missing             2018-01-01   2018-01-04
Present             2018-01-04   2018-01-05
Missing             2018-01-05   2018-01-22
```

In Missing rows, I should have 2018-01-03 instead of 2018-01-04 as end_date in first row.

Can someone help me in getting this query right?

Answer (score 1):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem, but it seems rather tricky:

```
select (case when fact_date is null then 'Missing' else 'Present' end) as grp,
       min(date_dt), max(date_dt)
from (select d.date_dt, t.fact_date,
             count(fact_date) over (order by d.date_dt) as seqnum, 
             sum(fact_date is null) over (order by d.date_dt) as seqnum_2
      from dim_date d left join
           fact_table t
           on d.date_dt = t.fact_date
     ) t
group by grp,
         (case when fact_date is null then seqnum else seqnum_2 end)
order by min(date_dt);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea5cf83ea8da0d67aa99a28e66452381) is a db<>fiddle.

This is tricky.  The idea is to find a constant value for the groups where the dates are present and are missing.  The idea is to count the number of present values up to a given date -- this is constant when the dates are missing.  And similar logic for the present values.

Comment: Can you tell me why you used count vs sum for both seqnum? I didn't get the idea there. Also I think sum(fact_date is null) is not possible in SQL. Trying to do using case but not working.

Comment: @harshini . . . `count(fact_date)` is the same as `sum(fact_date is not null)` (in MySQL).

Comment: So the flow of logic is Left join -> create seq based on fact_date is null or not -> Again create group based on fact_date and seq . But I still don't get why there is one more case in group by clause?

Comment: @harshini . . . This is -- in essence -- doing two group-and-islands problems at the same time, one for the matching dates and one for the unmatched dates.  That is what the outer `case` is doing.